# Er tut immer so, als bräuchte er keine Hilfe

Tags: declension

The verb "brauchen" is in the *Konjunktiv II,* however, I can not see this declension of the verb
http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-brauchen.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both versions are correct:

> ... als brauchte er keine Hilfe
>   ... als bräuchte er keine Hilfe

You can find a better declension table here: [Flexion von »brauchen« on wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:brauchen)

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to former times the alternative imperfect subjunctive »bräuchte« is nowadays classified as standard too.

Source: [Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&q=brauchen#v=snippet&q=5.%20brauchte%20%2F%20br%C3%A4uchte&f=false)